# how to mux video and audio segments files IIS smooth streaming (ISM) as MKV?

Tags: video, iis

I downloaded a video segments files to my PC. (I got the video from [here](https://hssodcplus-s.akamaihd.net/ondemand/playready/canalplus/d8/d8_1205547_5_D8/119435/d8-1205547-5-D8.ism/manifest))

Now I have two folders containing a lot of files:

- audio folder: it contain a lot of files with the extension .audio (Ex: `0_1000106666.audio`,`1000106666_2000000000.audio` ...)
- video folder: it contain a lot of files with the extension .video (Ex: `0_1000000000.video`, `1000000000_2000000000.video` ...)

I need to combine all those files, and convert all to one MKV file.

Can anybody help me with that please?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MKVToolnix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKVToolNix). It allows you to add all of those files into an mkv container and then mux them into an MKV file. It's pretty easy to use once you get the hang of it.

[Download page](https://mkvtoolnix.download)

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott, but it seems that MLVmerge is not compatible with .video and .audio extentions . I got this error message : "The file was not recognized as a supported format (exit code:0)"

Comment: It may help to check out what encoding those .audio/.video files are with this: https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo. It may just be as simple as renaming the extensions from (for example, .video to .mp4 if it's a .mp4 encoded file) for the MKVToolnix tools to recognize the files and use them. If not, you may need to encode them yourself before using Toolnix to make the .mkv.